# application configuration in biztalk

Tags: web-config, app-config, biztalk, biztalk-2013, biztalk-deployment

I developed an BizTalk orchestration where I am calling custom library method.
Since my custom library is consuming a web service and writing data into database therefore it reads various info like database connection string , WCF service endpoint address from `appconfig`. I put my custom library into GAC and deployed the BizTalk application but I am unable to find a place where I can put the `appconfig` which is used by custom library.

I Googled and found to append the config file in BTSNTSVc.exe placed under :\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft BizTalk Server 2013, however its not the recommended way.

Comment: The question is, why are you calling a custom library to call a web service and database when BizTalk can use ports to do that?  If you use ports your connection strings/URI's will be in your bindings.  What you are doing overall is not recommended unless there is a special need such as low latency.  There are various options for configuration.  The BizTalk config file as you mentioned is one option, a custom config file is another, however if the connection string includes passwords it would be better to store it in a secure location such as SSO.

Comment: We have placed many configuration items in the biztalk server config file. It works fine

Answer (score 0):

You can save your configuration in BTSNTSvc.exe.config, but that file contains biztalk host configurations.
Take in mind, that if you'll have a syntax error in that config file - you'll have troubles running biztalk engine.
Best solution is to use a cache layer which you will consume by C# class library from your orchestration.

Answer (score 0):

A better option is add to BTSNTSvc.exe.config a redirection to your config file, for example:

```
<appSettings>   
    <add key="myConfigFile" value="C:\MyProject\Config\myConfigFile.config" />
</appSettings>
```

This allows you to modify the configuration of your application without modify each time the BTSNTSvc.exe.config.